# Add border and shadow to the buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to add medium thick black border and shadow to the buttons that I have added in my iPad application. I have taken those buttons as custom as I have applied images on them. How can I add border and shadow to ht

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To add shadows and border is simple.

1) Add the QuartzCore framework to your target.
2) Import the framework header in the class where you want to add borders and shadows. (Or if you have custom class for the button then you can simple import this framework in that class.)
3) To add the border to the button use this code (where `button` is an `IBOutlet` connected with the button in interface):

```
[self.button.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
[self.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

4) To add the shadow to the button use the following code:

```
[self.button.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
[self.button.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[self.button.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
```

You can play around with the values and see how it will affect the behaviour.

Comment: Hey arslan, thanks buddy, your code worked. I just had to make some minor changes. I want to know one more thing. Initially my buttons had rounded corners and after applying border using your code, the corners are no more rounded. So how can I make them rounded as they were initially.
regards PC

Comment: @PrateekChaubey
Well good to know that it helped you :) ... And yes you can set the corner of the borders to be round rect with the following code 
                                   
`[self.button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];`

Comment: I use a custom UIButton class 'UIDictButton'.and use the code to custom my button but there is no shadow.only border. @Arsian if you to set cornerRadius may be you should set maskbouds to YES.

Comment: @frank. Can you share the code you are using to add shadow to your button. You have to play around with the shadowOffSet values in order to get desired result.

Comment: Hello Arslan, do you have idea how to do it with NSButton in Mac app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you were in Cocoa, you could use NSView's setShadow. (NSView is an ancestor of NSButton.) I don't see the equivalent method for UIView, so I don't think there is any simple way of doing that in iOS. Come to think of it, I don't think I've seen that effect in iOS apps, period.

But since you're using custom button images anyway, why not prepare images that include shadow and border?

Comment: well my designer has not provided me images included with border. I asked him to give me new images but now my manager says that he won't give me new images. I have to apply border and shadow myself.