# How to achieve this animation in UICollectionView while clicking a cell of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I recently got a requirement for achieving the animation as shown in the video in the following link.
[Cell Expansion](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3RXRFb0tRZEZDUUU/animation_meaninfultransitions_considerations_do.webm)

The animation i require is when the click is done on UICollection cell and it goes to the detail view. How to achieve this?

Comment: try this https://github.com/marmelroy/PeekPop

Comment: @techloverr objective c version is there for it?

Comment: bridge it or you can use circular segue

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the location of the cell in

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

After you have the x,y,w,h you can create a 
["popViewController"](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mjpopupviewcontroller)

Just change the animation to the animation you need and add some shade or some border to give more to the effect) [check here for border and shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923443/add-border-and-shadow-to-the-buttons)

For animation you can use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{ YOUR CODE }];
```